# Celerybeat not executing periodic tasks

Tags: python, django, django-celery, celerybeat

How do you diagnose why `manage.py celerybeat` won't execute any tasks?

I'm running celerybeat via supervisord with the command:

```
/usr/local/myapp/src/manage.py celerybeat --schedule=/tmp/celerybeat-schedule-myapp --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat-myapp.pid --loglevel=INFO
```

Supervisord appears to run celerybeat just fine, and the log file shows:

```
[2013-06-12 13:17:12,540: INFO/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Starting...
[2013-06-12 13:17:12,571: WARNING/MainProcess] Reset: Account for new __version__ field
[2013-06-12 13:17:12,571: WARNING/MainProcess] Reset: Account for new tz field
[2013-06-12 13:17:12,572: WARNING/MainProcess] Reset: Account for new utc_enabled field
```

I have several periodic tasks showing as enabled on `http://localhost:8000/admin/djcelery/periodictask` which should run every few minutes. However, the celerybeat log never shows anything being executed. Why would this be?

Answer (score 27):

celerybeat will just schecdule task, wont execute it.
To execute task you need to also start worker. You can start celery beat as well as worker together. 
I use "celeryd -B"

In your case it should look like:

> /usr/local/myapp/src/manage.py **celery worker --beat**
>   --schedule=/tmp/celerybeat-schedule-myapp --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat-myapp.pid --loglevel=INFO

or

> /usr/local/myapp/src/manage.py **celeryd -B**
>   --schedule=/tmp/celerybeat-schedule-myapp --pidfile=/tmp/celerybeat-myapp.pid --loglevel=INFO

Comment: Hey @YoK - can you help here, I'm running celery beat via celery multi with --beat and --schedule options however no tasks are being executed. I tried decorating task with `@app.periodic_task` with `CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks",)` but no success.

Comment: You don't want to use -B, considering that https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler says:

You can also embed beat inside the worker by enabling the workers -B option, this is convenient if you’ll never run more than one worker node, but it’s not commonly used and for that reason isn’t recommended for production use:

Answer (score 1):

We recently upgraded from **celery 4** to **celery 5**.

Apparently the `-l` flag has been removed, or re-named?

Works in celery4, but **not** celery 5:

```
celery -A pm -l info beat
```

**Remove `-l` :**

```
celery -A pm beat
```